# Efficiently coding the management of parameters with variable types in Java

Tags: java, typechecking

I am currently implementing a simulation in Java that requires an input of about 30 different parameters. Eventually, I want to be able to read these parameters from a file and also from a GUI, but I am just focusing on the file input for now. My simulation requires parameters that are of different types: Strings, ints and doubles and I currently have them as fields for the simulation e.g.

```
private String simName;
private int initialPopulationSize;
private double replacementRate;
```

Because these parameters are not all the same type I can't store them in an array and I have to read each one in separately using the same kind of code about 30 times. An example for three parameters:

```
//scanner set up and reading each line, looking for "(key)=(param)" regex matches
//if statement to check each param name against the key matched in file. Store param in that field if the name matches.
String key = m.group(1);
if (key.equals(PKEY_SIM_NAME)) {
    if (simNameSet) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("multiple values for simulation name");
    }
    this.simName = m.group(2);
    simNameSet = true;

} else if (key.equals(PKEY_INITIAL_SIZE)) {
    if (initialSizeSet) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("multiple values for initial population size");
    }
    this.initialPopulationSize = Integer.parseInt(m.group(2));
    initialPopulationSize = true;

 } else if (key.equals(PKEY_MUT_REPLACEMENT)) {
    if (replacementRateSet) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("multiple values for replacement rate");
    }
    this.replacementRate = Double.parseDouble(m.group(2));
    replacementRateSet = true;
 }
    //Add nauseum for each parameter.....
```

So I currently have a long and unweildly method for reading in parameters, and I will likely need to do the same again for reading from gui.

The best alternative I have thought of is to read everything into String fields first. That way I can write a simple few lines for reading in using a Map. Something like this (untested code):

```
//This time with a paramMap<String, String>, scanner set up as before
if (!paramMap.containsKey(key)) {
    paramMap.put(key, m.group(2));
}
else{
    throw new IllegalStateException("multiple values for initial population size");
}
```

However, this will be inconvenient when it comes to using these parameters from the Map, since I will have to cast the non-String params whenever and wherever I want to use them.

At this point I feel like this is my best approach. I want to know if anyone a little more experienced can come up with a better strategy for dealing with this kind of situation before I move on.

Comment: Could you reorganize these 30 parameters into distinct objects? Try to  look at some approach using Spring, where you could put the parameters in an xml file that also mentions the object type of each parameter and depend on Spring to load it into beans for you. Much neater. Of course, if you do not have control over the structure of the input configuration file, then this idea might not be useful.

Comment: This is something I haven't thought of. But I have deliberately made my input files as simple as possible (literally just a [key]=[value] on each line, unordered) so that anyone could create their own simulation. However, once I get around to the gui (I assume users could then just only use the gui instead of making their own files) this might be a good option for storing sets of parameters so that simulations can be quickly reloaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a base Parameter class or interface like:

```
interface Parameter {
    void parse(String s);
    Object getValue();
    ...
}
```

and a class for each type of parameter you want to have, e.g. `IntParameter`, `DoubleParameter`, `StringParameter`. Here's a sketch of an `IntParameter`:

```
class IntParameter implements Parameter {
    private int value;

    public void parse(String s) {
        value = Integer.parseInt(s);
    }

    public Object getValue() {
        return value;
    }
    ...
}
```

Then you can store your parameters in a `Map<String, Parameter>` and populate from various sources, like command-line options or properties.

---

A more type-safe but convoluted solution can be achieved if you don't store the value in parameter objects, but make parameters static objects that are used to access their values.
This is illustrated on the following example:

```
abstract class Parameter {
    private String name;

    public Parameter(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public abstract Object parse(String s);
}

class IntParameter extends Parameter {
    public static final IntParameter ANSWER = new IntParameter("answer");
    // Add more options here.

    public IntParameter(String name) { super(name); }

    public Object parse(String s) {
        return Integer.parseInt(s);
    }
}

class Parameters {
    private Map<Parameter, Object> params = new HashMap<Parameter, Object>();

    public int get(IntParameter p) {
        return (Integer)params.get(p);
    }

    public void put(IntParameter p, int value) {
        params.put(p, value);
    }

    public void putString(Parameter p, String value) {
        params.put(p, p.parse(value));
    }
}
```

This allows you to access parameter in a type safe manner:

```
Parameters params = new Parameters();
params.putString(IntParameter.ANSWER, "42"); // parse and store the value
int value = p.get(IntParameter.ANSWER);
```

The solution can be extended to other types.

Comment: This way feels very nice because it is very OO, but it still seems I will have the same problem of having to specifically cast every getValue() call (even more so, since I will now have to cast String parameters too). However, its one good way of storing everything in a Map, so I may well implement something similar. Thanks!

Comment: @kikimbob: To avoid casts you can have getInt, getDouble and getString instead of getValue in the Parameter class similarly to the Preferences API.

Comment: Wouldn't storing subclasses of Parameter in a Parameter HashMap mean I would have to cast for IntParamter anyway? :/

Comment: @kikumbob: If you want to store parameters in the same map, generics are not going to help, because you still need to have a single map value type and Parameter<Integer> is not the same as Parameter<Double>. You can have three different maps in which case IntParameter, DoubleParameter and StringParameter can be unrelated and return values of appropriate type. But then you'll have to search in multiple maps instead of one.

Comment: @kikumbob: If you prefer generics to casts, you can have something like `public <T> T as() { return (T)getValue(); }` in the Parameter class. In this case parameters can be accessed as follows: `param.<Integer>as()` which is similar to getInt, getDouble, getString solution.

Comment: Yep, sounds like pretty much the same. Casting is really bad thing though, so I'll stick with doing that.

Comment: @kikumbob: I've added a more type safe solution which doesn't require casts to get and set values, only in the implementation of Parameter classes.

Answer (score 2):

Parsing such files is a bad idea in the first place. It has been done for you already!

**Properties**

The mechanism that you can use is called "properties" in Java. This is regular text file containing key-value pairs just as you have described. It usually is of `*.properties` extension.

You do not have to use Spring or any other framework, since it's a part of regular JDK. So feel free to use it for your project!

**Want to be typesafe? Use Preferences!**

if you want to be typesafe, use "preferences" instead. Preferences API is an extension of regular Properties API, which will guarantee you proper type of required property.

**Documentation**

Using it all together is extremely simple. I don't want to repeat documentation, so please check out those two resources: [properties API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/properties.html), [preferences API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/preferences/index.html)

Comment: No problem. People tend to use only Properties API skipping the beauty of Preferences. They were both designed especially to aim problem you are dealing with, so have fun using it :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use property file for your situation. Property file consist of key/vapue pairs. A good utility for this approch is using of spring.
sample:

```
    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">

         <property name="locations">
                  <list>
                     <value>[your-path-1]</value/>
                     <value>[your-path-2]</value/>
                  </list>
         </property>
    </bean>
```

and for read key/value:

```
    <bean id="pum"
            class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager">
        <property name="persistenceXmlLocations" value="${your-key-1}"/>
    </bean>
```

Spring set value of **your-key-1** key persistenceXmlLocations member.
A good benefit of using spring is **Type Casting**, Spring own cast type of property to variable type.

Comment: I know very little about Spring and beans. Is this the format I would use for my input files, or some sort of XML class I can define?

Comment: Yes,you can specify input file as location property of placeHolderConfigurer. I thinks for xml goal must working more .

Answer (score 0):

The problem you mention is one of the main reasons for why I initiated and maintain a tool called [InPUT](https://github.com/feldob/InPUT). The Preferences API would work for your simple example, but it does not by default offer content validation, value ranges, or the treatment of non-primitive types (except from Strings). If you are dealing with simulations or optimization, you might want to read on.

You could define your parameters in an XML design space descriptor like this:

```
<SParam id="simName" type="String"/>
<NParam id="initialPopulationSize" type="integer" inclMin="10" inclMax="100"/>
<NParam id="replacementRate" type="double" inclMin="0.3" inclMax="0.7"/>
```

NParam (numeric) stands for primitive parameters, SParam (structural) for type parameters, when it comes to Java.

Your configuration (say, "config.xml") could now contain the following values:

```
<SValue id="simName" value="someName"/>
<NValue id="initialPopulationSize" value="20"/>
<NValue id="replacementRate" value="0.42"/>
```

From the code, all you do is call:

```
Design input = new Design("config.xml");
String simName = input.get("simName");
int initialPopulationSize = input.get("initialPopulationSize");
double replacementRate = input.get("replacementRate");
```

InPUT makes sure that the mappings are consistent with your descriptors. Once you set this up, you can add/remove, change the alternatives at free will without touching the code. You can use it to inject complex nested classes (see [InPUT main page, Example](https://github.com/feldob/InPUT#example-java)) in a code mapping descriptor, or define relationships between the numerical values in the parameter descriptor (like elite size is always smaller than population size). You can also create designs at random, with respect to the design space (for instance to find optimal parameter settings). The ambition is to make the tool available for various programming languages, for an easier language agnostic exchange of experimental descriptors (C++ is in the making). A variety of Java examples can already be found [here](https://github.com/feldob/InPUT/tree/master/Java/Source#input4j_examples).